# How i can upload multiple images in django to different parts of an article on a site?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am trying to allow users to use images in articles, how can I upload multiple images to different parts of an article on a site? And what's the best way to do it? There can be an unlimited number of pictures.

It's not a problem for me to upload multiple images to one location, but I don't know how to do it in different locations.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you say "article", are you using a CMS plugin of some sort?

Comment: If you are talking about something like putting multiple images in different parts of a blog post, you can use Django-ckeditor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, use any editor from the list: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/